# Cannot communicate with UiPath Platform The native part of the extension is not configured correctly. Re-install the extension from UiPath Studio

Tags: google-chrome, uipath, rpa

I am trying to use Chrome for Uipath Automation but I am not able to use getting the below error on Chrome extension while trying to use Chrome
**
Cannot communicate with UiPath Platform**

**The native part of the extension is not configured correctly.

Re-install the extension from UiPath Studio.**

It should work with chrome

Comment: You installed the Chrome Plugin?

Answer (score -1):

You can try below:

- reinstall chrome
- reinstall of uipath extension in chrome
- try on older version of browser